# WCF Data Services fail to respond a query including orderby

Tags: linq-to-entities, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a database view which I publish to other systems using WCF data services. The middle layer between the database and the WCF Data Services is built upon Entity Framework 4.1

When I query the view using a simple query without orderby, I get all results. If I include the orderby operator, the query fails with following error message (UseVerboseErrors is set to true):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code /> 
  <message xml:lang="de-DE">An error occurred while processing this request.</message> 
- <innererror>
  <message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</message> 
  <type>System.NullReferenceException</type> 
  <stacktrace>at lambda_method(Closure , StatesView ) at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count) at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count) at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.<TakeIterator>d__3a`1.MoveNext() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()</stacktrace> 
  </innererror>
  </error>
```

What do I do wrong? The view has a data service key defined on a column different to this one I want to use for sorting.

Here the query:

```
http://localhost:6000/MyView?$orderby=number desc
```

Comment: If I set SetEntitySetPageSize then the query fails even without the sortby operator...is there something wrong with the view? The view does not contain any SortBy commands...

Comment: I assume this is using a reflection provider and your MyView entity set is some kind of List<T> or so. Could you please verify that the list doesn't contain null elements in it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there were some null values in the column which were supposed to be used for sorting. After I excluded this values the query started to work. Thanks again! Create a new answer so that you cane get some points for answering my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments above the enumeration returned by an entity set query root (the property which returns the IQueryable) must not contain null items in it. If it does lot of things will go wrong, one of them being shown in the question above.